# How to perform bulk update using rails admin

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-admin, bulkupdate

[image]![enter image description here][2]

I just have to perform a Bulk update for my products using the action which i have defined. While inspecting the link, it displays the following:

```
         onclick="jQuery('#bulk_action').val('bulk_add_to_categories'); 
            jQuery('#bulk_form').submit(); return false;"
```

But when I click on it I get this error.

[image]

I need to do something like this

[image]
I need to have an separate UI for all the products that have came from that bulk action, and then put them into the selected categories, but I am not able to do that. Can anyone help me on this? Any help would be great. I have seen lot of tutorial and read the rails admin github page but I was not able to find anything helpful. Please guide me.